# Maven and Android

Tags: android, maven

I want to use Maven Dependencies injections in my Android Project. The goal of this is not to include the libraries into the project but to bind them during runtime. However, I was wondering if the internet connection is slow what is going to be happen? Will the project crash?  Will it become slow in compared with the occasion that I had include the libraries into the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing something up here. Maven doesn't do dependency injection. That's a spring term. Maven does build management which helps you adding the correct jars while your application gets built.

The necessary libraries are downloaded from the internet (or your local repository) when you compile your application. This is not done when the application is executed! Maven can add the correct jars in the right versions to your jar (if you configure Maven to do this).